# Unity привязка объекта к позиции

Tags: unity3d

Можно ли в юнити при наследовании привязать объект только к позиции родителя, без привязки к вращению?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если под "наследованием" в данном случае Вы подразумеваете "вложенный, дочерний объект" - то нет, т.к. теряется смысл объекта-родителя.
Попробуйте при изменении угла родителя менять угол у дочернего объекта на противоположный.

Comment: Проще создать "главный" объект и оба объекта сделать его детьми, позиция будет меняться при движении главного, а вращение будет у каждого из потомков свое.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, именно так, не спорю. Но вопрос-то был конкретно про родителя, а не общий объект-родитель, в котором вращаем дочерний объект... (тьфуты, дежавю какое-то с этими родительскими объектами и вращением XDD)

Comment: Ну это я так, на всякий случай дополнил, а то сам вопрос звучит как ошибка молотка